# TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function with bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have a bootstrap 2.32 modal which I am trying to dynamically insert into the HTML of another view. I'm working with Codeigniter 2.1. Following [Dynamically inserting a bootstrap modal partial view into a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022715/dynamically-inserting-a-bootstrap-modal-partial-view-into-a-view), I have:

```
<div id="modal_target"></div>
```

as the target div for insertion. I have a button in my view that looks like:

```
     <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-action="Message" data-toggle="tab">Message</a>
```

My JS has:

```
$.ajax({
    type    : 'POST', 
    url     : "AjaxUpdate/get_modal",
    cache   : false,
    success : function(data){ 
       if(data){
            $('#modal_target').html(data);

            //This shows the modal
            $('#form-content').modal();
       }
    }
});
```

The button of the main view is:

```
<div id="thanks"><p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#form-content" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Modal powers, activate!</a></p></div>
```

Here is what I'd like to store separately as a partial view:

```
<div id="form-content" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h3>Send me a message</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="contact" name="contact">
             <fieldset>

               <!-- Form Name -->

            <legend>modalForm</legend>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="user">User</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="user" name="user" type="text" placeholder="User" class="input-xlarge" required="">
                <p class="help-block">help</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="old">Old password</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="old" name="old" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-xlarge">
                <p class="help-block">help</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="new">New password</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="new" name="new" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-xlarge">
                <p class="help-block">help</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="repeat">Repeat new password</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="repeat" name="repeat" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-xlarge">
                <p class="help-block">help</p>
              </div>
            </div>



                </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>


    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Send!" id="submit">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Nah.</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click the button, the modal is inserted correctly, but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check if it will work with `jQuery(...).modal`. your jQuery may be in compatability mode, also check if jQuery is not included twice.

Comment: there is a big probability that bootstrap.js is not loaded before you try to call .modal()

Comment: mwebber - I'm not experienced with js , How do I "Check if it will work with jQuery(...).modal." I assume in the console somehow?  Etsitra , bootstrap.js is loaded in header before all this happens.

Comment: It means: try `jQuery('#form-content').modal();`

Comment: But where? in the console commandline ? I'm not thyat familiar with js workflows

Comment: instead of $('#form-content').modal(); use jQuery('#form-content').modal();

Comment: Anyone coming here for an answer like i did, see if its `.modal()` not `model()`. Such a lame mistake. drained me. :(

Comment: Why does it matter if jQuery is included twice or not?

Comment: ```window.$('#modalid').modal('hide');``` try this

Answer (score 214):

i just want to emphasize what **mwebber** said in the comment:

> also check if jQuery is not included twice

:)

it was the issue for me

Comment: Remember: Be sure to check ajax called files for jQuery too.

Comment: Also happened when I put lower version of jquery in a conditional include for ie8.  <!--[if lt IE 9]>

Comment: Also make sure no other libraries bundle jQuery in their own min files (DataTables does this in some cases)

Comment: Don't forget to check imports, like: import '../jquery-3.3.1.js';

Comment: ...and what does one do in that event? @gillytech

Comment: I am in a **catch 22** situation. In my Django app, I have menubar as well as modal windows. As per convention, most of my libraries are housed in the **parent** tamplate. Whichever pages have the modal, ref. to the bootstrap library is added. Now something funny happens with the menu bar - **they need to be clicked twice** to be activated. Other pages without the modal does not have this problem. Could somebody suggest as to what might be wrong?

Answer (score 106):

This error is actually the result of you not including bootstrap's javascript before calling the `modal` function. Modal is defined in bootstrap.js not jQuery. It's also important to note that bootstrap actually needs jQuery to define the `modal` function, so it's vital that you include jQuery before including bootstrap's javascript. To avoid the error just be sure to include jQuery then bootstrap's javascript before you call the `modal` function. I usually do the following in my header tag:

```
<header>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/path/to/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you @davetw12, it helped a lot

Comment: Correct Answer. :-)

Comment: Thank you, that is what fixed it for me. Find the script tag here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 54):

After linking up your jquery and bootstrap write your code just below the Script tags of jquery and bootstrap.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#div").on("click", "a", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery.noConflict();
    $('#myModal').modal('show');

  });
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 16):

I have resolved this issue in react by using it like this.

```
window.$('#modal-id').modal();
```

Comment: You solved it like this in reactjs? Mine failed

Answer (score 7):

Check that `jquery` library not included in html that load via `Ajax` .remove `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery[ver].js"></script>` in your `AjaxUpdate/get_modal`

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility is that one of the other scripts your including is causing the problem by also including JQuery or conflicting with $. Try removing your other included scripts and see if it fixes the issue.  In my case, after hours of needlessly searching my one code, I removed scripts in a binary search pattern and discovered the offending script right away.

Answer (score 7):

In my experience, most probably its happened with jquery version(using multiple version) conflicts, for sort out the issue we can use a no-conflict method like below.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
    // More code using $ as alias to jQuery
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('#modalID').modal('show');
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this issue in Laravel by modifing the line below in `resources\assets\js\bootstrap.js`

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery/dist/jquery.slim');
```

to

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery/dist/jquery');
```

Comment: jQuery slim doesn't include modal().

Comment: And that's why it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Run

```
npm i @types/jquery
npm install -D @types/bootstrap
```

in the project to add the jquery types in your Angular Project.
After that  include

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";
```

in your app.module.ts

Add

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in your index.html just before the body closing tag.

And if you are running Angular 2-7 include "jquery" in the types field of tsconfig.app.json file.

This will remove all error of 'modal' and '$' in your Angular project.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I use rails framework and require jQuery twice. I think that is a possible reason.

You can first check app/assets/application.js file. If the jquery and bootstrap-sprockets appears, then there is not need for a second library require. The file should be similar to this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

Then check app/views/layouts/application.html.erb, and remove the script for requiring jquery. For example:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I think sometimes when newbies use multiple tutorial code examples will cause this issue.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had `//= require jquery` after `//= require bootstrap`. Once I moved jquery before bootstrap, everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers din't work for me in my react.js application, so I have used plain JavaScript for this.

Below solution worked:

1. Give an id for close part of the modal/dialog ("myModalClose" in below example)

> ```
> <span>
>    className="close cursor-pointer"
>    data-dismiss="modal"
>    aria-label="Close"
>                      id="myModalClose"
> >
> ...
> ```

2. Generate a click event to the above close button, using that id:

> ```
>    document.getElementById("myModalClose").click();
> ```

Possibly you could generate same click on close button, using jQuery too.

Hope that helps.

Comment: is this considered as a good practice?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
Changing

```
$.ajax(...)
```

to

```
jQuery.ajax(...)
```

did not work. But then I found that **jQuery was included twice** and removing one of them fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could also be bootstrap modal being called before the javascript files are loaded which is what happened to me. I was calling a function on page load which resulted in this error. Resolved it by calling the function via the onload event.

```
window.onload = function () {
  callYourFunctionOrAjaxHere();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I guess you should use in your button

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#form-content"
```

instead of href there should be **data-target**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#form-content"
```

just be sure, that modal content is already loaded

I think problem is, that showing modal is called twice, one in ajax call, that works fine, you said modal is shown correctly, but error probably comes with init action on that button, that should handle modal, this action cant be executed, because modal is not loaded at that time.