# how to open modal popup on button click from server side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="3.aspx.cs" Inherits="KVTRANSAPORTS._3" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openModal() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        };
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" class="btn-info" runat="server" Text="Submit"
                OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"></asp:Button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
            aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close"
                            data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                            &times;
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">title
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        something
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                            data-dismiss="modal">
                            close
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                            save
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
    }
```

> it is giving error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your checked ~/Site1.Master ? Maybe your MasterPage includes jQuery library too?

[TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function with bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064176/typeerror-modal-is-not-a-function-with-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: yes it have.now i removed jquery library from 3.aspx page now its working properly.thank you so much