# $modal.modal is not a function in FooTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am following this [Tutorial](http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/examples/component/editing.html).

Here is my code (I've excluded my table HTML):

```
@model IEnumerable<JMWebApp.Models.Job>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Job Manager";
}

<div class="modal fade" id="editor-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editor-title">
    <style scoped> 
        .form-group.required .control-label:after {
            content:"*";
            color:red;
            margin-left: 4px;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <form class="modal-content form-horizontal" id="editor">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">x</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="editor-title">Add Row</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="number" id="id" name="id" class="hidden"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group required">
                <label for="reference" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Reference</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reference" name="reference" placeholder="Reference" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        var $modal = $('#editor-modal'),
            $editor = $('#editor'),
            $editorTitle = $('#editor-title'),
            ft = FooTable.init('#editing-example',
                {
                    editing: {
                        editRow: function(row) {
                            var values = row.val();
                            $editor.find('#id').val(values.id);
                            $editor.find('#reference').val(values.reference);
                            $modal.data('row', row);
                            $modal.modal('show');
                            $editorTitle.text('Edit row #' + values.id);
                        }
                    }
                });
    });
</script>
```

In my Layout file I define my scripts as so:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/footable.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/footable.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/footable.fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
```

I am having two issues with this. First of all the icons on the 'FooTable' are not displaying correctly, they just look like jumbled characters. I did read an answer before that there are a number of font files I needed to include.

I tried that but it didn't work, also I couldn't find any guidance on the FooTable website to include these icons.

Secondly I'm getting an error $modal.modal is not a function when I am attempting to edit the rows and show the modal. I also read a few answers to this in that my jQuery must be resolved before bootstrap, but as far as I can see in my Layout the scripts are loaded correctly.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bootstrap.min.js will be helpful for you, kindly read the below

Modal is defined in bootstrap.js not jQuery. It's also important to note that bootstrap actually needs jQuery to define the modal function, so it's vital that you include jQuery before including bootstrap's javascript. To avoid the error just be sure to include jQuery then bootstrap's javascript before you call the modal function.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28173513/3397630

Hope it was helpful

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you see anything specific in my code that is wrong? As far as I can see I am including both in the correct order.

Comment: It seems that bootstrap.min.js file is missing, kindly check for that