# TypeError: $(...).modalForm is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

This question is a bit long and hard to explain, but I'll try my best.

I have a todo website which allows users to add reminders. When a user right clicks the reminder, a context menu pops up with options such as edit, delete, etc. The button on the context menu changes based on which reminder the user selects:

```
function toggleMenuOn(e) {
    if ( menuState !== 1 ) {
      menuState = 1;
      menu.classList.add( contextMenuActive );
    }

    let reminder_id = e.target.id

    $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/get_reminder/',
    data: {
      'reminder_id': reminder_id
    },
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function (data) {
        let context_btn1 = document.getElementById("context_menu_btn1");
        let reminder_pk = data.serialized_reminder.toString(); 
        let reminder_url = "{% url 'update-reminder' 0 %}".replace(/0/, reminder_pk) 
        context_btn1.className = "update-reminder context-menu__link btn btn-light";
        context_btn1.setAttribute('data-id', reminder_url);
        change_var(reminder_url)
    }  
  });

  }

let context_btn_id = "/update_reminder/0/";
function change_var(new_name) {
    context_btn_id = new_name;
}

$("#context_menu_btn1").click(function() {
    $(this).modalForm({formURL: context_btn_id});  
});
```

I left out most of the other code, as I'm just working on the update functionality.

HTML for the context menu:

```
<nav id="context-menu" class="context-menu">
    <ul class="context-menu__items">
        <li class="context-menu__item">
            <button type="button" class="context-menu__link btn btn-light" id="context_menu_btn1" data-id=""><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
            //When the context menu shows up the data-id changes to /update_reminder/<reminder-pk>/
        </li>
        <li class="context-menu__item">
            <button type="button" class="context-menu__link btn btn-light" id="context_menu_btn2" data-id=""><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Delete</button>
        </li> 
        <li class="context-menu__item">
            <button type="button"class="context-menu__link btn btn-light" id="context_menu_btn3" data-id=""><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Share</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

When the edit button is clicked, a modal pops up with the form, which I use [django bootstrap modal forms](https://github.com/trco/django-bootstrap-modal-forms#installation). This works the first time, but as soon as the context_menu_btn1's data-id changes, it gives an `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modalForm is not a function`. A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064176/typeerror-modal-is-not-a-function-with-bootstrap-modal), but I have everything the solution says. I load jquery before bootstrap and I made sure jquery wasn't loaded twice.

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/main/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script> 

{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
```

I think it has something to do with multiple jquery instances, so the first loads and the second one doesn't. How would I solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: This is the added code for [Jeremy J Starcher's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807787/jeremy-j-starcher) Response:
I checked the value of this, and it is a button- which is what I want to call the modalForm on. I checked this with the update function with events, which work, and they are the same:
[image]

```
$(".update-event").each(function () {
  console.log($(this))
  $(this).modalForm({formURL: $(this).data('id')});
});
```

As a side note, update-event is called for each button displayed (I have a button on the side of each reminder), while the view-reminder button in the context menu changes depending on the reminder clicked. I also figured out that with each() the formURL doesn't change everytime the context_btn_id changes.

Note: I'm using jquery 3.4.1 and bootstrap is an installed package from pypi

Comment: Can we see your html and how you included the javascript source files?

Comment: I just updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint and look at the value of `this`

```
$("#context_menu_btn1").click(function() {
    $(this).modalForm({formURL: context_btn_id});  
});
```

I'm not able to run the code, but if I recall correctly, `this` will refer to the DOM element with the ID of `context_menu_btn1`.

That's not the element you are looking for.

Comment: I just checked the value of `this`, and it is what I want to call .modalForm with, as it works with update-event. I added more info to the question- hopefully it will help