# Open a Modal in ReactJS without click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-modal

I'm using following code to open a Modal in reactJS without any click:

```
window.$('#codeEmbedModal').modal('show')
```

But it is not opening a Modal. Am I doing anything wrong here? I used this way after looking at one of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064176/typeerror-modal-is-not-a-function-with-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: https://codepen.io/rajrs/pen/dMowNx Try this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using bootstrap modal. then you need to trigger the modal on hover or on load using jQuery.

```
$("#button").hover(function () {
    $('#modal').modal({
        show: true,
        backdrop: false
    })
});
```

also change css for modal

```
position: fixed; to position: absolute;
```

and change css as per need .

Answer (score 0):

function Example() {
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

return (
<>

Launch demo modal

```
  <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
        Close
      </Button>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
        Save Changes
      </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
</>
```

);
}

render();